# How to compute the integral to solve second order non homogenous ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to solve $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 17\frac{dy}{dx} + 16y = e^x+\sec^2(x)$$ I get the complementary solution to be $y_c=C_1e^{-x} + C_2e^{-16x}$. 
The first complementary solution, which is for $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 17\frac{dy}{dx} + 16y = e^x$$ is $y_{p1}=C_3e^x$.

To find the second complementary solution, which is for $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 17\frac{dy}{dx} + 16y = \sec^2(x)$$
we compute the Wronskian, we have $$W(e^{-x},e^{-16x}) = e^{-x} (-16e^{-16x}) - e^{-16x}(-e^{-x})=-15e^{-17x}$$ So, the particular solution is : . 
$$y_{p2}=-e^{-x}\int \frac{e^{-16x}\sec^2(x)}{-15e^{-17x}} dx + e^{-16x}\int\frac{e^{-x}\sec^2(x)}{-15e^{-17x}} dx$$
which simplifies to
$$y_{p2}=\frac{1}{15}e^{-x}\int e^x\sec^2(x)dx -\frac{1}{15} e^{-16x}\int e^{16x}\sec^2(x)dx$$

I am stuck here to find the integral. Any help appreciated, or is there another method to solve this ODE?

Comment: Are you sure the ODE is written correctly? It seems there is at least a sign error.

Comment: @Moo you are right, I typed wrong ODE, in fact, It is not ODE asked. Let me fix it

Comment: @Moo I have edited the question

Comment: Are you sure about the $\sec^2(x)$ ? Moreover, the solution of  $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 16\frac{dy}{dx} + 17y =0$ is not $y_c=C_1e^{-x} + C_2e^{-16x}$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I am sorry, that was a typo as well. I have fixed it. and yes, it is $\sec^2(x)$. The only change is the 16 and 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all $C_3=\frac 1{34}$.

Then, as I suspected (refer to my first comment), I think that you face a terrible problem with the $\sec^2(x)$ since the solution involves hypergeometric functions.

Using a CAS, I received (please fasten you seat belt)
$$\frac{1}{975} \left((8-i) e^{2 i x} \left((3+2 i) \,
   _2F_1\left(1,1-\frac{i}{2};2-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)-8 i \, _2F_1\left(1,1-8
   i;2-8 i;-e^{2 i x}\right)\right)-65 i \left(\,
   _2F_1\left(-\frac{i}{2},1;1-\frac{i}{2};-e^{2 i x}\right)-\, _2F_1\left(-8 i,1;1-8
   i;-e^{2 i x}\right)\right)\right)$$ Even with $\sec(x)$ the same kind of monster appears.

I am pretty sure that the equation is in fact 
$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} + 17\frac{dy}{dx} + 16y = e^x+\color{red}{\sin^2(x)}$$

Probably one more typo in a textbook.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: solve the equation $$\lambda^2+16\lambda+17=0$$ after the ansatz $$y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$$
we have
$$y''=\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}$$
$$y'(x)=\lambda e^{\lambda x}$$
so $$\lambda^2 e^{\lambda x}+16\lambda e^{\lambda x}+17 e^{\lambda x}=0$$

Comment: the old DE is a typo. I have updated it.

Comment: i saw the typo in you post

Comment: then shouldn't it be $\lambda^2+17\lambda+16=0$?